# How to use Multi-pane layouts with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

The Android Design guidelines suggest using [Multi-pane layouts](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html#combining-views), but as far as actually implementing this there are no examples given. Specifically I'm referring to the dual-pane layout used in conjunction with `ViewPager` like in the **People** app shown in the guidelines.

Does anyone have some advice or examples to give on implementing this?

In the screen shot:

You can swipe with `ViewPager` back and forth between the `About` and `Updates` lists or you can tap on the photos to page over. You can see a small part of the `Updates` tab while viewing whatever you have in the `About` tab and visa versa. Specifically, I want to know how to create this multi-pane layout. The screen shot is from the **People** app in **Ice Cream Sandwich**.

**SOLVED:**

**I ended up creating my own open sourced library for this widget. You can find it at this address:
https://bitbucket.org/adneal/tabcarousellib/wiki/Home**

[image]

Comment: Please update question with more specific detail and reqired screen shots.

Comment: have you try anything regarding this ? if no then wait for my answer.

Comment: I took a shot at it before I posted. I created all the necessary layouts, I took them from the People app, but I couldn't get the source right. I'm not sure how you're doing it, but the People app uses several custom classes that can get a little overwhelming when you're trying to reverse engineer them.

Comment: I have posted the answer. that's what you want right ?

Comment: @iDroid Explorer: Ok i got what you want. I will edit the answer after couple of days. till that wait.

Comment: I edited my OP. The Gigbeat creators are releasing this as an open source project. I had never read that until just now.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is solved. It's been almost a year and I don't think Gigbeat ever open sourced the carousel widget as they said in their blog post. It's a shame, they should have only announced it once they did open source it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as I got you want to implement the SplitView in android.

If yes then Use this link to get information of [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) from developer site.
Use this [Demo of developer site](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html).

If not getting solution then use this Demo Example : [Demo](https://github.com/k9mail/splitview/blob/master/example/src/com/fsck/example/splitview/Home.java)

If still its not what you want then also let me know.

I will like to help you.

Comment: I don't need help with `Fragments`. That's not what I'm looking for. I suppose it's difficult for me to explain with words. If you've ever used the **People** app in **Ice Cream Sandwich** then it's obvious what I mean. The [Gigbeat beta](http://blog.gigbeat.fm/post/18425833350/gigbeat-1-2-beta) also has this custom layout.

Comment: See what? The **Gigbeat beta**? The link was in my previous post, but here it is directly. [Gigbeat beta](http://gigbe.at/uploads/gigbeat-1.2-beta.apk)

Answer (score 1):

For View Pager first you go through this [svn](http://viewpagerexample.googlecode.com/svn).I have gone through android developer site.If you want multi-pane Layout with out Fragment then it very difficult.I will suggest you to go for the Fragment and achieve your multi-pane layout.

But one i can understand your problem also as Fragment are available from Android 3.0 (API level 11).If you want to target device below this then it became necessity to use View Pager.So you have to work hard to achieve it.

[Study this for creating horizontal List View](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Try this first **If you can Customize it**
[ViewPager Indicator in android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: One More thing i want to say multi-pane layout are used in Tablet.as we have lots of space to show data.And Tab support came from 3.0.Above 3.0 Fragment supported by android.So if you do not have any specific requirement then use fragment

Comment: I did see you answer, but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't need help with `Fragments` or `ViewPager`. The widget in the screen shot is a result of several custom classes that rely on new ICS APIs. I added a link in the OP under `SOLVED` that directs you to the Gigbeat website and talks specifically about what I'm looking for and how they're going to release this widget as an open sourced library project. I'm not rewarding the bounty to anyone, because no one has answered my question. `ViewPagerIndicator` is not what I'm looking for.