# ViewPager Like Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-viewpager

I'd like to help me make a viewpager as Facebook People May to Know In the first situation the item 0 has not left margim and item 1 is shown in preview In the second situation three items are shown, and the item 1 in the middle and the item 0 and 2 in the item preview

I would like an example, to seek information dynamically

Sample Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To show corners of neighbor fragments make use of the xml of fragments. Reference : [Android tip viewpager with protruding children](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/)

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries/15773055#15773055) too will help you to achieve that.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516646/android-card-fragment-animation/33516820#33516820) also for an elaborated solution.

Comment: I would like an example, to seek information dynamically

Answer (score 0):

**I did this by changing my viewpager's padding based on the position.**

```
carouselViewHolder.carouselViewPager.setPadding(Utils.dpToPixels(context, 12), 0, Utils.dpToPixels(context, paddingRequired - 12), 0); // initial padding for position 0
            carouselViewHolder.carouselViewPager.setPageMargin(Utils.dpToPixels(context, 12)); // margin between pages

        carouselViewHolder.carouselViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                            if (position != 0) {
                                if (position == playCardData.getPlayCards().size() - 1) {
                                    carouselViewHolder.carouselViewPager.setPadding(Utils.dpToPixels(context, finalPaddingRequired - 12), 0, Utils.dpToPixels(context, 12), 0);
                                } else
                                    carouselViewHolder.carouselViewPager.setPadding(Utils.dpToPixels(context, finalPaddingRequired / 2), 0, Utils.dpToPixels(context, finalPaddingRequired / 2), 0);
                            } else {
                                carouselViewHolder.carouselViewPager.setPadding(Utils.dpToPixels(context, 12), 0, Utils.dpToPixels(context, finalPaddingRequired - 12), 0);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                        }
                    });
```