# View Pager Transformation bring to top like cards

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I Would like to achieve the following

[image]

I was able to use the following library
https://github.com/Hongchae/CoverFlowPager

and after some customization i was able to have this

[image]

Now i want to adjust the pages to appear like the first image

Appreciate your help ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this sample library https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager

Answer (score 1):

For showing the preview of left and right fragments you have to set the following values:

// This for avoiding the truncate effect

```
viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
```

// This for setting the padding for seeing the other fragments

```
viewpager.setPadding(left,0,right,0);
```

To modify the space between the fragments in the viewpager use

```
viewpager.setPageMargin(int);
```

probably this post will help you [ViewPager show next and before item preview on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572605/viewpager-show-next-and-before-item-preview-on-screen)