# How to show viewpager with next pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to show the next item in *viewpager* as a shadow that user select which would look like following image:

[image]

I have used *viewpager-transformer* but it doesn't work.
Anybody help me to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767105/view-pager-transformation-bring-to-top-like-cards

Comment: https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack

Comment: http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/09/viewpager-cards-like-duolingo.html

Comment: Thanks intellij-amiya  but i want to use  page transformer for doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can use FancyCoverFlow

```
<at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        fcf:maxRotation="45"
        fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
        fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
        fcf:unselectedScale="0.4" />
```

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

http://davidschreiber.github.io/FancyCoverFlow/

http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/09/viewpager-cards-like-duolingo.html