# ViewPager with prev and next image visible

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-pagetransformer

[image]

I am searching for this for my whole day but I cant find any library or code to achieve this `view pager animation`. I want to achieve exactly like this(As shown in below image) center image is now showing image and previous and next image will be displayed in back. Thanks in advance please help me by sharing your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30572605/3022836)

Comment: it is not working for me @Kunu

Comment: im using Viewpager not Viewpage Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
mViewPager.setPageMargin(Utils.dpToPx(24));
mViewPager.setPadding(Utils.dpToPx(44), 0, Utils.dpToPx(44), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for is here.

You customize them according to your design or you can get basic idea how is works might be help full for you.

1) [**FancyCoverFlow**](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)

[image]

2) [**Coverflow Android**](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

[image]