# how to make Slider Animation

Tags: android-layout, android-viewpager, slider

How to make some different type animation in side slider. Is there any library. if any library please provide me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ViewPager

[ViewPager show next and before item preview on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572605/viewpager-show-next-and-before-item-preview-on-screen)

Check above url and find the solution.